# How to write the output from terminal to new file using linux commands without the alignment changes?

Tags: ls

---

I have tried the following commands to write the linux commands output in new file but  the aligned varies.

ls (in terminal)

```
1m_complete.pl   current_sample.pl   rsdb.tcsh         
1m_complete.pl~  current_sample.pl~  getp.pl
```

But while trying ls >> ls_out(Alignment Varies)

```
 1m_complete.pl   
 current_sample.pl   
 rsdb.tcsh         
 1m_complete.pl~  
 current_sample.pl~ 
 getp.pl
```

My expected output:

```
 1m_complete.pl   current_sample.pl   rsdb.tcsh         
 1m_complete.pl~  current_sample.pl~  getp.pl
```

Comment: Some programs modify/adapt/change their behavior depending on whether the standard input or standard output is a terminal or not. That's how they are. There is nothing you can do, except use a different program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` checks if the STDOUT is attached to a terminal (`isatty(1)`), if not then it outputs each filename in a separate line.

You can instead use `ls -C >out.txt`, or `echo * >out.txt` to get the listing in columnize format, although in both cases the output will not be in exact form as shown by `ls` when output is going to a terminal.

Comment: `echo *` will produce a single (long) line. `printf '%s\n' * |column` will produce columns aligned over as many lines as needed similar to `ls -C` but in at least some cases I tested not exactly the same widths.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` behave differently when outputing to a terminal or a file.

terminal out put is column by default, while file output is one file per line.

just use

```
ls -C
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mention, `ls` alters its output depending on whether its standard output is a terminal or not.

```
ls -C
```

forces `ls` to use a columnar output, but by default it formats lines so that they fit in 80 columns. If you want to get output matching the results you get in your terminal, you need to export the `COLUMNS` variable:

```
export COLUMNS
ls -C > output
```

or, if you only want to specify `COLUMNS` for `ls`:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS ls -C > output
```

(assuming your shell knows the current width of the terminal and makes it available in the `COLUMNS` variable itself).